# Can `listen_addresses` system configuration setting in Postgres stop pre-authentication exploits?

Tags: postgresql, authentication, connections

You can [set various configuration parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/config-setting.html) for Postgres by either editing the `postgresql.conf` file manually or by calling [`ALTER SYSTEM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersystem.html) commands.

One of those config settings is [`listen_addresses`](http://GUC-LISTEN-ADDRESSES). To quote the documentation:

> Specifies the TCP/IP address(es) on which the server is to listen for connections from client applications. The value takes the form of a comma-separated list of host names and/or numeric IP addresses. The special entry * corresponds to all available IP interfaces. The entry 0.0.0.0 allows listening for all IPv4 addresses and :: allows listening for all IPv6 addresses. If the list is empty, the server does not listen on any IP interface at all, in which case only Unix-domain sockets can be used to connect to it. The default value is localhost, which allows only local TCP/IP “loopback” connections to be made. While client authentication (Chapter 20) allows fine-grained control over who can access the server, listen_addresses controls which interfaces accept connection attempts, which can help prevent repeated malicious connection requests on insecure network interfaces. This parameter can only be set at server start.

➥ Does this mean `listen_addresses` theoretically stops pre-authentication exploits?

Is there any engagement between the Postgres server and the incoming connection which might possibly result in an exploit? Or will the forbidden incoming connection be blocked without any engagement?

Of course, ideally, a firewall on the host operating system would also be in place to block unwanted incoming connections. But let’s ignore firewalls for the purpose of this Question.

Comment: Any process on the OS wanting to receive input from network asks the OS to listen on some specific sockets, by providing the list of local IP to listen on, or asking for all of them with a shortcut. Then the OS makes sure that any network input coming to one of these specific address (and correct port) goes to the relevant process that started to listen on. If someone tries to connect to another IP address still existing on the host, the OS will not pass the data to the process if it does not listen on that IP. The process does not see the connection at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `listen_addresses` filters connections before postgres sees them

> ➥ Does this mean `listen_addresses` theoretically stops pre-authentication exploits?

Yes. If PostgreSQL's postmaster isn't listening on a given interface (as identified by its local address) then no remote host may connect to it via that interface. The operating system will report the TCP port as closed and send a TCP RST to the connecting host; PostgreSQL code is never reached, so PostgreSQL bugs cannot be exploited, even pre-auth ones.<sup>1</sup>.

## `listen_addresses` blocks pre-auth exploits

> Is there any engagement between the Postgres server and the incoming connection which might possibly result in an exploit? Or will the forbidden incoming connection be blocked without any engagement?

No. `listen_addresses` configures the listening TCP socket at the operating system level, binding it only to the network interface(s) specified<sup>2</sup>. It filters on *the connection target address specified by the remote host*. The OS won't tell PostgreSQL about connections to other interfaces at all.

Note that the same is is *not* true of `pg_hba.conf`. `pg_hba.conf` controls *remote-host source address* filtering and authentication configuration. The PostgreSQL postmaster *does* handle any connection that comes in on a listened-on address and is then rejected by `pg_hba.conf` configuration.

You can do sender-address based filtering before PostgreSQL sees the connection by configuring operating system firewall rules. Those *will* prevent PostgreSQL pre-auth exploits by blocking the connection from ever reaching PostgreSQL.

So if you know that only the hosts in network 111.1.0.0/16 have any business connecting to your PostgreSQL it's a good idea to configure a firewall rule accordingly. You should set `pg_hba.conf` as a fallback, but the firewall rule should stop anyone even attempting to connect to postgres itself.

## Understanding authentication flow

To connect to postgres you must pass a series of "gates" of sorts. Ignoring UNIX sockets for this explanation, we have:

- OS network and TCP level, before you hit PostgreSQL code:

  - Any border router or firewall between you and postgres must permit the TCP connection
  - Any operating system firewall configured on the postgres host must permit the TCP connection
  - `listen_addresses` - postgres must be listening on the interface or the OS treats the TCP port as closed
  - Any network security extensions like TCP Wrappers (`/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny`) must permit the connection. (Assuming they're supported on your OS and postgres is compiled to use them)
- Within PostgreSQL code:

  - A `pg_hba.conf` `host`, `hostssl` or `hostnossl` rule is found when matching by source-address, ssl mode, target dbname and requested username
  - The matched `pg_hba.conf` rule must not specify `reject`
  - If SSL client certificate checks are enabled, the SSL client certificate satisfies the configured CA cert.
  - The requested username and database name must both exist in the PostgreSQL catalogs
  - The requested username or a role it inherits must have the `LOGIN` option in the PostgreSQL catalogs
  - The requested user must have `CONNECT` rights to the requested database. (By default the `public` role all users are a member of has `CONNECT` rights, but you can `REVOKE` that and `GRANT` it only to specific users or roles/groups).
- *Yay, you've connected*

If a connection is blocked at an earlier stage, it never interacts with later stages. I haven't checked the exact ordering of the dbname vs username privilege checks, but the rest is right.

*I ignored `pg_ident.conf` and username mappings, client cert DN mappings, the details of things like SSPI/GSSAPI and low level auth methods, etc here.*

Now, if you're using UNIX sockets (`unix_socket_directories`, and a `libpq` `host` address that's a path or omitted entirely), the PostgreSQL stage is the *same* except that `pg_hba.conf` matching doesn't check source-address and looks for `local` lines instead of `host`, `hostssl` or `hostnossl` lines. The `peer` auth mode is supported to require a unix username to postgres username match. Details in the manual.

## Exposing PostgreSQL to the Internet

Let me note that pre-auth exploits for PostgreSQL are [not *wholly* unheard of](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2013-1899/), but are rare. It's fairly routine to expose PostgreSQL on the Internet directly.

You should use `hostssl` in `pg_hba.conf` to enforce SSL connections to protect authentication exchanges and make casual scanning a bit harder. And you should adopt the same protective measures you use for any other Internet-exposed service: use fail2ban or similar, use an IDS, monitor logs, and have firewall rules to exclude anything that you know has no business connecting.

*However*, if you don't *need* to expose PostgreSQL to the Internet, don't do it. In particular, if you only need loopback connections, bind PostgreSQL to the loopback address(es) `127.0.0.1` and `::1`. Or even better, use [unix sockets](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-UNIX-SOCKET-DIRECTORIES).

## See also

- [The "Client Authentication" chapter of the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html)
- [`listen_addresses`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-LISTEN-ADDRESSES)
- [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)
- For Ubuntu and (mostly) Debian:

  - [Ubuntu docs for Ubuntu's PostgreSQL packages](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/postgresql.html.en)
  - [Ubuntu community help wiki for PostgreSQL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL)

---

<sup>1</sup> The attacker could still exploit OS bugs in the network stack. Or (very unlikely) they might be able to use tricks like source-address spoofing to fool a buggy OS into letting it send an initial packet to PostgreSQL even when it's bound to a different interface. Any modern, sensibly configured OS will prevent that.

<sup>2</sup> Internally each `listen_addresses` entry is used to make a separate listening TCP socket. For UNIX-like OSes it's passed to the `bind(...)` call on each socket. See `postmaster.c` around line 1012, `if (ListenAddresses)`, and see the `StreamServerPort` adapter in `src/backend/libpq/pqcomm.c` around line 532.